# removing child from a child

Tags: javascript, removechild

I am having trouble removing the child of a child of an object created using JS.

Basically once I create a comment object I appendChild(replyBox) to it. Inside the replyBox there is a cancel button which is supposed to completely delete the replyBox.

Here is the code :

```
 function Comment(message){
    var self = this;
    var message = message;

    var comment = document.createElement("li");
    comment.id = "comment";
    comment.style = "display: none;";
    comment.textContent = message;

    createButtons(comment);

    var parent = document.getElementById("wall");
    parent.appendChild(comment);
    return comment;
}
function deleteComment(comment){
    var parent = document.getElementById("wall");
    parent.removeChild(comment);
}

function newReply(comment){
    var buttons = comment.getElementsByTagName("input");
    buttons.item(0).disabled="disabled";

    var replyBox = document.createElement("div");
    replyBox.id="replyBox";

    var replyTxt = document.createElement("input");
    replyTxt.type="text";
    replyTxt.value="Write a reply";
    replyTxt.onfocus = "if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';" ;
    replyTxt.onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue;";
    replyBox.appendChild(replyTxt);

    createButtons(replyBox);

    comment.appendChild(replyBox);  
}
function createButtons(parent){
    var button = document.createElement("input");
    button.type = "submit";
    if(parent.id=="comment"){
        var reply = button.cloneNode();
        reply.value = "reply";
        reply.addEventListener("click", function(){newReply(parent)},false);
        parent.appendChild(reply);

        var deleteBtn = button.cloneNode();
        deleteBtn.value = "delete";
        deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){deleteComment(parent)},false);
        parent.appendChild(deleteBtn);
    }
    else{
        var submitBtn = button.cloneNode();
        submitBtn.value = "submit";
        //reply.addEventListener("click", function(){newReply(parent)},false);
        parent.appendChild(submitBtn);

        var cancel = button.cloneNode();
        cancel.value = "cancel";
        cancel.addEventListener("click", function(){cancel(parent)},false);
        parent.appendChild(cancel);
    }
}

function cancel(replyBox){
    replyBox.parentNode.removeChild(replyBox);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   cancel.addEventListener("click", function(){cancel(parent)},false);
```

Which `cancel` is which? You have an object called `cancel` as well as a function with the same name. Try renaming one.

Comment: lol thank you for that... I spent so much time on this... I forgot for a second that I had the same name for two different things.

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem here:

```
    comment.id = "comment";
```

If you're setting all IDs of the comment elements to `comment`, the DOM may be getting confused.